# Printing manually crafted string not working

Tags: c, string, memory

```
int main() {
  char a = 'b';
  char* c = &a;
  *c = 'a';
  *(c+1) = 'j';
  *(c+2) = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", (char*)&a);
}
```

It prints the character 'a' and 'j' but then it prints junk, seemingly ignoring the null terminating char.

Why?

Comment: What do you think is at the address `c+1` and `c+2`?  More relevantly, why do you think it is safe to write to those locations?

Comment: Undefined behaviour — you've not allocated space for `c[1]` or `c[2]` (which you wrote in the obscure `*(c+1)` and `*(c+2)` notation).

Comment: It's because I was checking a decompiled code with very similar logic, but it doesn't allocate a buffer...I should further investigate. Now I know that this should blow up because it doesn't have the size previously allocated. I should brush up on my C knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do causes *Undefined Behavior*, because the char pointer `c` doesn't point to a block of memory able to store your string.

So when you advance the pointer by 1, or/and 2 you access memory that is not relevant to where pointer `c` or `a` points to, and you will either cause a segmentation fault, or access memory that your program has allocated, but that's random and bad.

---

You need to allocate space for `a` (How much? 2 characters, plus the null terminator), which gives you an array of chars, of size 3. Then set pointer `c` to the beginning of `a`. Now you are allowed to do pointer arithmetic with `c`, from 0 to 2 (size of array - 1), and assign the desired characters and null terminator via the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[3];
  char* c = a; // set 'c' point to the start of the array 'a'
  *c = 'a';
  *(c+1) = 'j';
  *(c+2) = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

> aj

Comment: It didn't work. Still printing junk. But thanks for the lightning fast reply.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", (char*)&a);` should be `printf("%s\n", a);`.

Comment: Also, you can use malloc() to allocate memory dynamically, which means that you can reserve space for data while the program is running, instead of hard coding the amount. Remember to use free() as well when you malloc() memory. See this for reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory

Comment: This method use `a` pointer just a pointer to actual array elements

Answer (score -2):

Because you need to allocate a buffer, you can't just take a pointer and write at that address.

I'm guessing you're doing this for learning purposes, because you could just do:

```
char *a = "bj\0";
printf("%s\n", a);
```

If you want to append characters, I strongly suggest to use std::string though.
Otherwise, you would have to do something like this:

```
char a[3]; // You need to allocate a defined size!
char* c = a;
*c = 'a';
*(c+1) = 'j';
*(c+2) = '\0';

printf("%s\n", (char*)&a);
```

or without a cast:

```
printf("%s\n", c);
```

Sorry I didn't compile, so there may be typos.

Comment: It's because I was checking a decompiled code with very similar logic, but it doesn't allocate a buffer...I should further investigate. Now I know that this should blow up because it doesn't have the size previously allocated. Ty.

Comment: Yes there is a typo, see my answer MGambsy, and tell me what you think. This `char* c = &a;` cannot compile.

Comment: std::string in C? `*(c+1)` will add char [3] as &a has a type char [3]

Comment: @gsamaras you're right, I edited it, but I don't think taking the address of the first item of an array of char makes sense (char *c = &a[0]), I edited my answer with "char *c = a", which is more what it is. I mean you answer works but I just think it adds more complexity.

Comment: Agreed @MGamsby. Moreover, you can adapt your printing function like mine's to minimize complexity. Do you like my answer now, I updated it! I will upvote yours, because you showed effort.